# KDB and DS_Store

Tags: macos, kdb

I receive an error if I try to load a splayed kdb table from disk using `\l path/to/db` and that the folder contains a `.DS_Store` (automatically created by OS X). If I delete the `.DS_Store` file everything loads fine.

Any way to tell kdb to ignore these files?

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Droppy, guess it's more a kdb question?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a programming question, so doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen this issue before. I don't think there is a way. Splayed or partitioned structure has to be clean in order for them to load into kdb. You will have to delete `.DS_Store` or make sure it doesn't get created.